# Why were two people — a body double and a stunt double — used for a character who barely appears in “The Mandalorian?”

Tags: casting, effects, stunts, acting

Season 2, episode 8 of *The Mandalorian* features a brief — but significant — cameo from a character well known in the *Star Wars* universe.

While CGI technology was used to change the face of this character to fit into the timeline of *The Mandalorian* somehow [two people were credited](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13052880/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) for the physical body of this character in the episode:

- **Double for Jedi**: Max Lloyd-Jones
- **Stunt Double for Jedi**: Matt Rugetti

Why was this done?

The character appeared for less than a few minutes total on screen, the stunts didn’t seem to strange or risky at all. The action this character engaged in seemed to be purely interactions with CGI adversaries and environments and not much else.

Is there some Hollywood bureaucratic reason this character’s brief appearance was handled this way? Something like stunt doubles are not SAG members and thus cannot “act” as well?

From my perspective, the stunt double could have easily been the body double as well so this seems a bit odd to me considering this character’s face was digitally altered.

Comment: Thank you for the careful wording & completely non-plot-spoilered question (I'm starting the series tonight, now I can binge it;) (I didn't click the link, of course, just in case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Pay-scales.

#### Simple economics.

The stunt double would cost three times as much as the body double.
If only a day or two of stunts was required and the rest of the time simple walking/standing was all that was needed, then getting in a cheaper replacement would be the most economical solution.

You can’t ask a non-stunt-registered actor or SA to do stunts - “health and safety” and all that. Stunts are insured differently from “players” and their pay-scales are totally different.

Conversely, you *can* ask stunts to “act,” but you’re still going to be paying them stunt rates.

---

FWIW, my “qualification” for this answer is I work in the industry. Some of this information can be easily Googled, but others rely on “in world” word of mouth.

Proof of stunt rates isn’t easy to obtain as you have to be a member - you can look at bits of this but not all of it on [the British Stunt Register](http://www.thebritishstuntregister.com/) site. Basic day rate is about £300 but variable depending on Stunt Grade. I don’t know the full range as I’m not stunts, but this is from conversations over the years on set. The British Stunt Register is *the authority* in this territory.

SA (supporting artist) rates are much more easily searchable (most SA agencies have this info publicly available on their site) - such as [this site](https://www.thecastingnetwork.co.uk/rates.asp) (amongst others). Movies usually work under the FAA/PACT agreement. Basic day about £100 plus 20 quid for doubling.

This is all UK information. The US and other territories no doubt have their own agreements, but I would doubt there is a territory where this basic difference in rates would not apply.

Comment: Having now watched it, I can see the clear delineation. Stunts for swinging weapons, double for standing in a room. (again without trying to add spoilers)

Comment: Yup, moved the plot on nicely :) The fighting needed someone skilled in 2-handed sword and katana. No matter how late the call to use a double in 'act 3', it would make no financial sense to get that guy back in. Bear in mind the shoot schedule would have been 6 months minimum, probably more for a show like this as they have to finagle the CGI "live" to The Volume. Even allowing for covid testing they could have got an SA costumed & ready to go in 2 days easily; same day if they were really, really pushed. I've often had calls which start "How soon can you get to [studio]?"